# Angular Material ripple overflows on buttons in Safari

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I click on a button using Safari ripple effect overflows on rounded buttons. It works properly in Chrome.

I found out that Angular actually make a few more elements inside a button, I tried to change some parameters – didn't work at all.

[image]

Any way to fix this?

[image: Pressed button]

HTML

```
<button  mat-button type="submit" class="cta-button" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid" [(ngModel)]="disabled">
          <span >Zaloguj</span>
        </button>
```

CSS

```
.cta-button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 27px;
  font-size: 17.6px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 60deg, #1354DF 15%, #DB16AC);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( 60deg, #1354DF 15%, #DB16AC);
  background: linear-gradient( 30deg, #1354DF 15%, #DB16AC);

  width: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(42,53,170,0.2),
              0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cta-button:disabled  {
  background: lightgray;
  color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(42,53,170,0.0),
              0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  cursor:auto;
}
```

Comment: use angular material package and it does all the things for you

Comment: mat-button is actually part of Angular Material

Comment: Hi! I just tried out your code and it seems to work fine on Safari(Version 12.1.2) desktop, basically the ripple effect is only on the button area. What version are you trying on?

Comment: Or is there more css/js involved somehow in the component your populating the button tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `!important` behind your css changes to overwrite the automatically generated stuff from Angular.

For example:

```
.cta-button:disabled  {
  background: lightgray !important;
  color: grey !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(42,53,170,0.0),
              0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0) !important;
  cursor:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I know about this function, however, there no seem way to change how does ripple behave inside the button.

Comment: Did you try `outline: 0;` ?